# Typo in the list of reasons for closing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed

There is a typo in the list. The phrase "overly broad" is misspelled as "overy broad".

Comment: Whoops. Nobody ever realised...

Comment: So tempted to close this just to have the typo front-and-center :)

Comment: Also, we'll get it fixed up soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed

Somehow a crazy old typo (hundreds of database revisions ago) got back into the new site creation process.